# Is it possible to unload my orgs redshift data to an s3 bucket outside of my org?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to unload my organizations redshift data to a vendors s3 bucket. They have provided me with Access Keys and Secret Access Keys but Im getting a 403 Access Denied Error. I want to make sure its not an issue with the credentials they sent me and am reaching out. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have a look here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-s3-cross-account/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, That's possible. Here are the steps.

1. unload the redshift data to bucket associated to the current account.

   unload ('select * from table')
   to 's3://mybucket/table'
2. Mybucket should have replication configured to the vendor s3 bucket. use the below [s3 replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-replication.html) to configure the replication